# Override css with your own css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a layout coming from a 3rd party source which I need to override in my own css. I am able to change the styles by using common css rules like:

```
#someid-div input[type=checkbox]{
    display:block;
}
```

and

```
#someid-container .h1 {
    font-size:20px !important;
}
```

but now i have a different situation in which I need to wrap around or introduce additional tags to show the desired layout. e.g.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                <input name="email" class="form-control" id="email" type="text">
            </div>
 </div>
```

to something like:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
       <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <input name="email" class="form-control" id="email" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible in CSS? Or do I need to use jquery for it? A code snippet would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: so you want to change the html too? yes you have to use jquery/ajax for this.

Comment: use jQuery to do this! would be a simple task!

Comment: this html is coming from a 3rd party and will be changing depending upon different selections from their drop downs, so how can I use my jquery to change the html based on a specific selection

Comment: @sam, Yes you can do it with Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using jquery. Something like this will do.

```
    $(".row").empty();
    var html = '<div class="form-group col-sm-4"><label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label></div><div class="form-group col-sm-6"><input name="email" class="form-control" id="email" type="text"></div>';
    $(".row").append(html);
```

Insert it after your intended operation is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in jQuery (untested):

```
var label = $("label[for='email']");
var parent = label.parent();
$("<div>").setClass("form-group col-sm-4").append(label).insertBefore(parent);
```

Comment: Thanks, as I explained above that this html is dynamically being loaded from a 3rd party (based on a dropdown provided by them), so is there anything we need to do to check when we have 'email' box loaded and when we have 'passport' box?